# How to add block near a product image in a product detail page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-images

How to add block near a product image in a product detail page in Magento 2

[image: https://prnt.sc/no8cfd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in **\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml** and clean cache

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
        <container name="" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="" before="skip_gallery_after.target">
            <block class="" name="" template="" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below code and change block identifier name

app\design\frontend\YourVendor\YourTheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-identifier" before="product.info.media">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block-identifier</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Clear cache and check..

Comment: i want to add a  block in custom module

Comment: via xml or phtml ??

Comment: add a layout in xml

Comment: If you have created custom module, you can use my code as i mention in above answered. just have to use module layout xml file.